# Prevent gummi bears from drying out

Tags: candy, gelatin

I have tried making gummi bears but have the problem that they dry out very fast. I'd like to make gummi bears that could be eaten for a couple days. After five days they dried out so much it was impossible to chew them anymore.

Am I missing some other ingredient to prevent it from drying out after just a couple days? This is the recipe I used

```
0.5 liter water
20 g gelatine 
1 teaspoon salt 
325 g sugar (65%)
A dash of glucose syrup
Flavoring
```

Comment: Maybe it's more a matter of storing them than of the recipe?

Comment: I've looked at the ingredient lists of several commercial Gummy bears. They all seem to include an oil or wax that could be a mold release agent, or a moisture retention covering. It might also help to add a few ml of Glycerin, a humectant, to your recipe. Humectant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humectant

Comment: I am a bit surprised here, since freshly made gummy bears don't taste like store bought, so people usually complain of the opposite thing (texture not dry enough when eaten fresh). Do you want them to have a jello texture, or do you want them to be like storebought but find that they are even drier?

Comment: It takes a pretty thick plastic bag to keep water in gummis. I use 6 mil zip locks, kept in an airtight plastic box, and get a lifetime of about a month.

Answer (score 1):

Try 50/50 sugar corn syrup. The corn syrup may help with retention

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing as baked goods and seal them in with a piece of moist bread or orange peel just be warned it will change the aroma of whatever is sealed with it. I.E.bread is better with baked goods and orange peel would be better with the gummy bears.

Answer (score 1):

You need a recipe that includes significant glycerin.
As a [humectant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humectant) it'll help your gummis retain water, chewiness.
Ro store the things, you'll need thick 5-6mil ziplocks. Thinner than that and water leaches out pretty quickly.
If you get a bag that's gone dry, you can simply add enough water to bring it up to its fresh weight, reseal the bag, and wait 3-4 days for the water to sink in.
Your stale gummis should be good as new.